# Generate a unique string without special characters

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have created a method in c# that takes unique email as input and returns base64 string. I am using MD5CryptoServiceProvider for this purpose. Here is the code:

```
public string GenerateHash(string str)
    {
        str = str.ToUpperInvariant();
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] emailBytes = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
        var base64Email = Convert.ToBase64String(emailBytes, 0, emailBytes.Length);
        return RemoveSpecialCharacters(base64Email);
    }

    private static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(str, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+", "", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    }
```

But the issue is it returns a string with special characters (eg /, ==) and I have to remove those special characters by myself using regex or something else but is there anyway I get a unique string without special characters so I don't have to use regex myself. Also is there any possibility I get a string of no more than 12 characters

Comment: there might be another special character too. I want to restrict all the special characters even (. and _)

Comment: How about converting the byte[] (base64 string) to hex?

Comment: You can convert hash array to [hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/311165/4685428)

Comment: If you don't mind the extra length, the hexadecimal representation of the MD5 is 32 digits of only `0-9` and `A-F` characters.

Comment: I have edited my post, can you tell me now?

Comment: No, I can't affort extra length

Comment: @Ask - If you can't afford extra length then you can't get rid of special characters. They enable the encoding to be shorter. If you restrict the encoding alphabet then the length must increase.

Comment: @Ask - Of course, if you're happy to throw away information you can make them as short as you like.

Comment: @Ask - Also, please make sure you post real code. As it stands your code doesn't compile.

Comment: @Ask - And `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` is `IDisposable`. Don't forget to clean up after yourself.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the purpose of all of this?

Comment: @Ask - And finally, when I fix your current code it seems to work as you want it to. What's wrong with the existing code?

Comment: Actually I don't want to use regex. I just want to convert to base64 without special characters

Comment: @Ask - But these "special" characters are legal [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) characters. If you remove them, you have something that resembles but actually **isn't** base64. The question is, what is your "problem" with these characters? Do you need them in a URL? There is URL-Encode for that.

Comment: @Enigmativity, thanks for pointing out my mistake. I should use 
using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create()) instead